# Publishing/copying artifacts from one Ivy repository to another one

Tags: ant, jenkins, ivy

We are using ant with ivy through Jenkins to do our daily builds. Initially we want to publish our artifacts to our test Ivy repository and once testing is done, we want to copy the same artifacts to our released Ivy repository without rebuilding them. Does the Ivy or Jenkins has any tasks that help with this? Also, when we publish them to test repository we are planning on using integration status, is there a way we can change the status to release when we copy to released Ivy repository? We have multiple modules that we do builds for but only selected of them need to be moved to released Ivy repository. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [install](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/install.html) task to copy artifacts between repositories.

A better solution to consider is using the [staging suite](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging.html) a feature of Nexus professional. It works by creating a temporary repository for each release candidate, which can be promoted until deemed worthy of release. Other repository managers have similar features, worth considering rather than building your own.

Comment: Thanks Mark!  If I am using install, how can I change the module's status from integration to release status when installing on the released repository? We don't have funding to buy Nexus :(

Comment: @tiggertigger The install task was really only designed to mirror artifacts. It does not support this usecase.